# Cakephp HtmlHelper for images not picking-up images from webroot

Tags: html, image, cakephp

I have cakePHP (2.7.0) installed on WAMP. My images are located under app/webroot/img.

In the view I have the following:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image( 'img2.gif', array('alt' => 'img2')); ?>
```

When the img element renders the "src" is set to /app/img/img2.gif instead of /app/webroot/img/img2.gif. What am I missing?

Comment: If your image directory is webroot/image , then your code is perfect. Check your image extension name. Did you change your default image directory ? In browser console webroot folder will be ignore. your directory should see like /yourapps/img/img2.gif.

Comment: The image extension is correct and yes my image dir is APP_ROOT/app/webroot/img. I am not sure I follow why the browser console would ignore webroot since /app/img/img2.gif does not render the image. When I type /app/webroot/img/img2.gif into the browser only then can I see the image.